# Как вывод с несколькими строками преобразовать в список и к каждому элемента списка добавить undo

Tags: python

В выводе  box_model получаю многострочное значение по типу:

```
ntp server 1.1.1.1
ntp server 3.3.3.3
ntp server 6.6.6.6
```

Я хочу сделать из этого вывода список и к каждому элемента списка добавить undo что б получить список типа

```
undo ntp server 1.1.1.1
undo ntp server 3.3.3.3
undo ntp server 6.6.6.6
```

Проблемная часть кода:

```
box_model='''ntp-server 1.1.1.1
ntp-server 2.2.2.2
ntp-server 3.3.3.3'''
box_model.split('\n')
ncommands = ['undo {}'.format(undo) for undo in  box_model]
print(ncommands)
```

Но на выходе получаю совсем не то что ожидаю

```
['undo n', 'undo t', 'undo p', 'undo -', 'undo s', 'undo e', 'undo r', 'undo v', 'undo e', 'undo r', 'undo  ', 'undo 1', 'undo .', 'undo 1', 'undo .', 'undo 1', 'undo .', 'undo 1', 'undo \n', 'undo n', 'undo t', 'undo p', 'undo -', 'undo s', 'undo e', 'undo r', 'undo v', 'undo e', 'undo r', 'undo  ', 'undo 2', 'undo .', 'undo 2', 'undo .', 'undo 2', 'undo .', 'undo 2', 'undo \n', 'undo n', 'undo t', 'undo p', 'undo -', 'undo s', 'undo e', 'undo r', 'undo v', 'undo e', 'undo r', 'undo  ', 'undo 3', 'undo .', 'undo 3', 'undo .', 'undo 3', 'undo .', 'undo 3']
```

Подскажите пожалуйста где может быть ошибка

Comment: Укажите в вопросе, что именно вы получаете

Comment: в приведенном коде много лишнего, не имеющего отношения к вопросу. Удалите все, что не относится к вашей задаче. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать `split("\n")` - разбиение строки по переносу строк и strip() - что бы лишние пробелы убрать.

```
box_model='''ntp-server 1.1.1.1
            ntp-server 2.2.2.2
            ntp-server 3.3.3.3'''

ncommands = ['undo {}'.format(undo.strip()) for undo in  box_model.split('\n')]
print(ncommands)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, думал что у меня переменная box_model разбилась на список построчный после команды box_model.split('\n'), поэтому не писал.

Comment: @Дмитрий а это не команда, это функция, которая принимает строку и возвращает список строк, но никак не изменяет исходную строку (строки в Python вообще не изменяемы) или значение в переменной, в которой строка лежала. Результат функции нужно принять и как-то обработать.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо. Даже не заметил что перенес это из исходного примера.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе у вас все правильно, кроме того, что результат `split()` нужно куда-то присвоить, т.е. можно просто заменить

```
box_model.split('\n')
```

на

```
box_model = box_model.split('\n')
```